# spring batch: scope("step") failed

Tags: java, spring

I could use `scope="step"` in xml configuration without any issue, but if use it as annotation as below
. it throws the following error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'reader': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reader': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope

The main point is:

Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread;

what's the root cause?

```
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("step")
    public ItemReader<Source> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("read file of "+fileName);
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        FlatFileItemReader<Source> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Source>();

        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileName));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Source>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Source>() {{
                setTargetType(Source.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use either of below to two ways available

```
   @Scope(value="step",
   proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS)
```

Or

```
 @Bean
 @StepScope
```

Comment: i did not understand the difference between @Scope("step") and @StepScope , though it resolved my query.Can you please explain the difference between them

Comment: Hi @b22, if you check the implementation, `@StepScope` is equivalent to `@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`.